# How to unpickle a Result object returned by an IBMQ experiment?

Tags: programming, qiskit, ibm-q-experience

I have executed an experiment using IBMQ and receive a `Result` object.
I am writing the ASCII repr of the result with `f.write(res)` into a file and see a line like

```
Result(backend_name='ibmq_16_melbourne', backend_version='1.1.0',...
```

How can I reconstruct the Result object from that line? Which methods do I have to call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution:
to serialise instead of `print(res)` I need to do:

```
print(res.to_dict())
```

To load the serialized string (eg. `line` from a file)

```
dict = eval(line)
res = Result.from_dict(dict)
```

all of the above with

```
from qiskit.result import Result
```

Answer (score 1):

You could recreate the object by reading the parameters and then creating a new result object `result = Result(parameters)`. You can see the method that does this [here](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/97cf6771378df9f132a88e27ed4e21586aa1befb/qiskit/result/result.py#L27).

If you have access to the account that submitted the job you can also simply retrieve the job from the backend again using `get_job()`.

Comment: Thank you! You mean that I should first parse the string I have in the file?

I did not want to use the remote API to get the results, because preferred the local way of analysis. That way I can send the analysis script to other people without send them the API key.